# Why won't network links open in pdf documents from SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, chrome, office-online-server, edge

We have multiple pdf documents in a SharePoint 2016 document library and we use Office Online Server.  Within the pdf documents are links to network files.  The pdf files open in a web browser (Edge Chromium and Chrome).  Clicking a link (points to a network file, word/excel document) in the pdf from the web browser does nothing.  The document never opens.  No errors.  No information in browser developer tools.  Opening the pdf in Adobe Acrobat Reader and then clicking a link to network files, opens the file.  Is SharePoint preventing the network link from opening the file?  Is Office Online Server preventing the network link from opening the file?  Is this a browser issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern browsers do not support the `file://` protocol for security and sandboxing reasons. The solution would be to move those documents to cloud storage and re-link them.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, network links in PDF files are currently not supported to open.